# Weird characters returned by selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I am using Selenium and PhantomJS and I have noticed that sometimes I get weird results. Any idea why? Is that an encoding issue?

```
LOG_PATH = '/vagrant/browser.log'
WINDOW_SIZE = (1680, 1200)
def create_driver():
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=LOG_PATH)
    browser.set_window_size(*WINDOW_SIZE)
    return browser

d = create_driver()
d.get('https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/')
el = d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote_currency_input"]')
```

The value of the element has weird characters:

```
el.get_attribute('value')
'ç¾å'
```

While the id is fine:

```
el.get_attribute('id')
'quote_currency_input'
```

Taking a screenshot via `d.save_screenshot('test.png')` does not reveal any issues in the page.